# How to Convert Struts2 datetimepicker value to SQL datetime so that it can be saved to a SQL table

Tags: java, sql, datetime, struts2, datetimepicker

I am using Struts 2 dojo datetimepicker in my application. How can I convert my action class property of `String` type (which is a value from datetimepicker) to a SQL `datetime` so that I can save the value in a SQL Table? If it is possible, please provide me with sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a Type Converter. This is a class that extends from StrutsTypeConverter.

```
public class MyConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter{
    //this method converts received object into String
    public String convertToString(Map map, Object object){
        if(object instanceof Date){
            Date date = (Date) object;
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //this method convert the received String into a 
    public Object convertFromString(Map map, String[] values, Class clazz) {
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            return parseValue(values[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
    //this method do the conversion
    public Date parseValue(String value) {
        value = value.trim();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            return simpleDateFormat.parse(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have created the converter class, it is necessary create a properties file, the name of this file must follow the next pattern:

```
NameOfYourAction-conversion.properties
```

This must be placed where your action is. Inside, you must put the name of the field you want to convert and the name of your converter, like this:

```
myfield = com.app.converter.MyConverter
```

With this, Struts will do the conversion automatically.

Anyway, here is the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/type-conversion.html).

Regards.